# sort an array of objects leaving first field

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like below:

```
result =
[
   {"id": 1,"Name": "K"},
   {"id": 2,"Name": "I"},
   {"id": 3,"Name": "A"},
   {"id": 4,"Name": "C"},
   {"id": 5,"Name": "G"},
   {"id": 6,"Name": "B"}
]
```

I sorted my object array alphahbetically like below

```
result.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name);
   });
```

but i wanted to sort my object leaving my first object i.e, K

i wanted my array to look like

```
[
   {"id": 1,"Name": "K"},
   {"id": 3,"Name": "A"},
   {"id": 6,"Name": "B"},
   {"id": 4,"Name": "C"},
   {"id": 5,"Name": "G"},
   {"id": 2,"Name": "I"}
]
```

how to achieve this?

Comment: before you sort it remove the first object with yourArray.splice(0, 1);

Answer (score 6):

You basically extract the first element, sort the array, and add it again using [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
const [first, ...rest] = [
   {"id": 1,"Name": "K"},
   {"id": 2,"Name": "I"},
   {"id": 3,"Name": "A"},
   {"id": 4,"Name": "C"},
   {"id": 5,"Name": "G"},
   {"id": 6,"Name": "B"}
];

const result = [first, ...rest.sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name))];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Even though I posted an answer myself, this one looks more elegant than mine! +1

Answer (score 2):

```js
let first = results.shift()
results.sort()
results.unshift(first)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `slice()`

```
[
   {"id": 1,"Name": "K"},
   {"id": 3,"Name": "A"},
   {"id": 6,"Name": "B"},
   {"id": 4,"Name": "C"},
   {"id": 5,"Name": "G"},
   {"id": 2,"Name": "I"}
].slice(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var result =
        [
            {"id": 1,"Name": "K"},
            {"id": 2,"Name": "I"},
            {"id": 3,"Name": "A"},
            {"id": 4,"Name": "C"},
            {"id": 5,"Name": "G"},
            {"id": 6,"Name": "B"}
        ]

    var firstObj=result.shift();

    result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name);
    });
    result.unshift(firstObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) and [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) with [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like so.

```
let firstItem = result.shift();
result.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name);
});
result.unshift(firstItem)
```

**Shift:**

Removes the first item of the array and returns it.

**Unshift:**

Places an item at the start of the array.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
const result = [
   {"id": 1,"Name": "K"},
   {"id": 2,"Name": "I"},
   {"id": 3,"Name": "A"},
   {"id": 4,"Name": "C"},
   {"id": 5,"Name": "G"},
   {"id": 6,"Name": "B"}
]

const firstElement = result.shift();
result.sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));
result.unshift(firstElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```js
result =
[
   {"id": 1,"Name": "K"},
   {"id": 2,"Name": "I"},
   {"id": 3,"Name": "A"},
   {"id": 4,"Name": "C"},
   {"id": 5,"Name": "G"},
   {"id": 6,"Name": "B"}
]

result = [
  result.slice(0, 1),
  ...result.slice(1).sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name))
]

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the first item and check the parameters if the value is the first item. This item is sorted first, then all other elements are sorted behind.

This approach keeps the same object reference of the given array.

```js
var result = [{ id: 1, Name: "K" }, { id: 2, Name: "I" }, { id: 3, Name: "A" }, { id: 4, Name: "C" }, { id: 5, Name: "G" }, { id: 6, Name: "B" }],
    first = result[0];    

result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (b === first) - (a === first) || a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name);
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```